# Strange issue changing extent projection from UTM to latlon (WGS84) and back again to UTM

Tags: r, gis, r-raster, rgdal, map-projections

I'm trying the following procedure (I apologize for mistakes but it is the very first time here). I've the raster dtm.temp expressed as follows:

```
> dtm.temp
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 668, 965, 644620  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 64.9, 92.6  (x, y)
extent      : 437230.1, 499858.6, 5138842, 5200699  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +init=epsg:32632 +proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : elev 
values      : 362.8404, 3584.865  (min, max)
```

Using this extent I convert it in longlat in the following way

```
# I build a spatial dataframe with extent data from dtm.temp
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:2, X = c(dtm.temp@extent@xmin, dtm.temp@extent@xmax),
                           Y = c(dtm.temp@extent@ymin, dtm.temp@extent@ymax))
coordinates(df) <- c("X", "Y")
crs_text <- crs(dtm.temp, asText=TRUE) # extracting crs from dtm.temp 
proj4string(df) <- CRS(crs_text) 
ext.lonlat <- spTransform(df, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
ext.lonlat

> ext.lonlat
class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
features    : 2 
extent      : 8.183449, 8.998142, 46.40024, 46.95982  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 1
names       : ID 
min values  :  1 
max values  :  2
```

at this point I use the extent (expressed as longlat) to crop the following raster dtm.temp1 (always in longlat but with a different initial extent and higher resolution)

```
> dtm.temp1
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 9956, 14656, 145915136  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.0002777778, 0.0002777778  (x, y)
extent      : 7.857917, 11.92903, 44.27042, 47.03597  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory 
names       : elev
values      : -18, 4543  (min, max)
```

then

```
dtm.temp1.crop <- crop(dtm.temp1, ext.lonlat)

> dtm.temp1.crop
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 2015, 2933, 5909995  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.0002777779, 0.0002777772  (x, y)
extent      : 8.183473, 8.998195, 46.40014, 46.95986  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

and then I project again in UTM the raster cropped at the same extent (or at least, so I believed..)

```
 # crs_text as defined above 
  dtm.temp1.crop.proj <- projectRaster(dtm.temp1.crop, crs=crs_text)

>dtm.temp1.crop.proj
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 2033, 2968, 6033944  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 21.2, 30.9  (x, y)
extent      : 437083.4, 500005, 5138362, 5201182  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +init=epsg:32632 +proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : elev 
values      : 360, 3603.655  (min, max)
```

as you can see the two extent dtm.temp (the starting one) e the final dtm.temp1.crop.proj seems to be too much different.

```
extent dtm.temp           : 437230.1, 499858.6, 5138842, 5200699
extent dtm.temp1.crop.proj: 437083.4, 500005,   5138362, 5201182
```

The error (in meters) is:

```
> 437230.1 - 437083.4
[1] 146.7
> 499858.6-500005
[1] -146.4
> 5138842 - 5138362
[1] 480
> 5200699-5201182
[1] -483
```

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but I'm going crazy trying to understand what...

Someone is so patient to help me? Thanks in advance!

I add some more information trying to clearify on the basis of the comment of Mike. 
Using a different approach (easier but computationally time consuming) I follow this steps:

```
    > dtm.temp.extent <- extent(dtm.temp) # is the extent fixed
    > dtm.temp.extent
    class       : Extent 
    xmin        : 437230.1 
    xmax        : 499858.6 
    ymin        : 5138842 
    ymax        : 5200699 
# then I project directly the second raster dtm.temp1 using the crs 
# with projectRaster (very slow)
    > dtm.temp1.proj <- projectRaster(dtm.temp1,crs=crs_text)
# then I crop to the fixed extent
    > dtm.temp1.proj.crop <- crop(dtm.temp1.proj, dtm.temp.extent)
# this is what I obtain        
    > extent(dtm.temp)
    class       : Extent 
    xmin        : 437230.1 
    xmax        : 499858.6 
    ymin        : 5138842 
    ymax        : 5200699 
    > extent(dtm.temp1.proj.crop)
    class       : Extent 
    xmin        : 437233.6 
    xmax        : 499852 
    ymin        : 5138857 
    ymax        : 5200688
```

the error now appears to me very reasonable:

```
> 437230.1 - 437233.6 
[1] -3.5
> 499858.6 - 499852
[1] 6.6
> 5138842 - 5138857 
[1] -15
> 5200699 - 5200688 
[1] 11
```

The reason of the first approach is only because I'm trying to speedup the code (very time consuming in the second approach).

(***Edited***) I add, it may be useful for someone, an image of the problem in the first workflow (the two points of the extent - LL and UR - far from raster even if on a different raster respect to the one above in the question) and the solution suggested by Mkennedy that works fine (using four points unprojecting all four corners of the raster, LL, UL, UR, LR and then taking the min/max of the 8 values). I was not catching the rotation that occurs when unprojecting to lat/lon using only the LL and UR coordinates. Taking the true min/max, the results are more closely (as in the 2nd workflow)

[Position of the raster vertex following a different approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYSEM.jpg)

Comment: I added a dump of `dtm.temp1.crop` so that the rasterization values are visible.

Comment: Thank you Mike.  Unluckly the magnitude of the errors I expect it is of same order of the res of the raster. Trying to answer to your question the extent defines a georeferenced spatial area in the two different rasterization (with different cell resolution). The rasterization (then the cell size, alias resolution) change but the extent should remain almost the same as function of the res (look here as example https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212705/cropping-raster-to-same-extent-using-r.

Comment: Well it is the same order of the finer (second) bitmap, but it is much lower (factor of 15 or so) than the original bitmap. Is that so surprising?  These are non-linear transformations (I think).

Comment: Your argument is reasonable. That leave me with some doubts, not being neither me an GIS expert, is the fact then if I change the approch first projecting directly  _dtm.temp1_ with `>projectRaster(dtm.temp1, crs=crs_text)` , in UTM, and I check the extent the error become more reasonable... I don't understand why...

Comment: How much is the error then?

Comment: @MikeWise I added some lines above in which you find the error (I don't know if it is correct to edit the question...but). Thanks for your time!

Comment: I deleted my answer as I don't think it contributes anything over your edited question.